# Using RxJS and axios, how do you fetch data onClick in React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

I'm struggling with how to fetch data using RxJS and axios onClick in a React component. But getting closer, I think. Any attempts I've tried either run when component mounts, not onClick, or don't run at all even onClick.

Basically, how to call onClick and how to pass a payload. There just seems to be nothing online to explain this which i would expect to be a common situation.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const getData$ = new Subject(observer => {
    axios
      .post(`/my-url/`, **how to get payload to here**)
      .then(response => {
        observer.next(response.data);
        observer.complete();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        observer.error(error);
      });
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const subs = getData$.subscribe({
      next: res => setData(res),
    });
    return () => subs.unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Button onClick={() => getData$.next(payload)} />
  );
};
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you can pass in the payload in `getData` like this

```
const getData$ = (payload) => new Subject(observer => {
    axios.post(`/my-url/`, payload)
        .then(response => {
            observer.next(response.data);
            observer.complete();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            observer.error(error);
        });
});
```

This basically just creates an anonymous function called `getData` that returns your `Subject`. It's equivalent to this:

```
const getData$ = function (payload) {
    return new Subject(observer => {
        axios.post(`/my-url/`, payload)
            .then(response => {
                observer.next(response.data);
                observer.complete();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                observer.error(error);
            });
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks. So by turning it into a function means it won't be called immediately? And am I calling getData$ the correct way? () => getData$.next(payload)

Comment: I can't subscribe to getData$ now since turning it into a function. Seems like there must be another solution. Thank you though

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?